# show that $g(x)= x^n f(\frac 1x) \in \Bbb F[x]. $ where $\Bbb F $ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\Bbb F $ be a field and $f(x)=\sum_0^n a_i x^i \in \Bbb F[x]$.

1. Show that $g(x)= x^n f(\frac 1x) \in \Bbb F[x]$
2. Show that if $r \neq 0$ is a root of $f(x)$ then $r^{-1}$ is a root of $g(x)$
3. Find all primes $p$ such that $ x+2$  is factor of $x^4 +x^3 +x^2-x +1$ in $\Bbb Z_p[x] $

#### My solution for 2:

If $r$ is a root of $f(x)$ then $f(r)=0$. Substituting $r^{-1}$ in $g(x)$:

\begin{align}
g(r^{-1}) &= (r^{-1})^n f(r^1) \\
\Rightarrow g(r^{-1}) &= r^{-n}\cdot 0 \\
\Rightarrow g(r^{-1}) &= 0
\end{align}

#### My solution for 3:

$x+2$ is a factor of $x^4 +x^3 +x^2-x +1$ $\Leftrightarrow $ $-2$ is a root of $x^4 +x^3 +x^2-x +1$. $(-2)^4+(-2)^3+(-2)^2-(-2)+1 \equiv 0\ \mathrm{mod}\ p \Leftrightarrow 15 \equiv 0\ \mathrm{mod}\ p$.
The only primes satisfying this condition are $3$ and $5$.

#### Questions

1. How do I prove 1?
2. Are my solutions for 2 and 3 true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solutions are correct.

To prove (1) simply write down
$$x^nf(x^{-1}) = x^n\sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^{-i} = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i x^{n-i} \in \Bbb{F}[x]$$

For example, if $f=x^2+2x-3$, then
$$g=x^3f(x^{-1}) = x^3(x^{-2}+2x^{-1}-3) = x(1 + 2x-3x^2)$$

Comment: Is this enough to prove (1)

Comment: @Sara Yes. It was easy, wasn't it? :D

Comment: Yes thank you Crostul

Comment: Are you sure that (3) correct????

Comment: Yes, I am sure.